# Could not load file or assembly when trying to reference a Netcore50 library WPF project from NetCore50 exe WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-core-5-preview-2

Issue:
I have a Netcore50 project (Exe) that references another NetCore50 project (library), when try to run the Necore app it throws below mentioned exception

System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'classlibrary1.csproj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

**Project structure**

Application

a.Netcore Exe project

1.NetCore Library project (dependent for Exe)

Suggest a solution to resolve this

Comment: What is `classlibrary1`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is library project reference and it added as dependent to exe project project

Comment: Well, it sounds like you need an assembly reference instead of a project reference.

Comment: @RobertHarvey    Why it is specific netcore, the same scenario working fine in.Net Framework project,
I got this exception only on Necore project

Comment: @max: How does your project files look like? Does it work in .NET Core 3.1?

Comment: @mm8 please check description that I have added my application structure same issue in Netcore 3.1 also